# Java - what compile-time class is returned by this.getClass() in a parameterized class method?

Tags: java, generics

I've seen similar questions and have a workable solution, but I do not have a deep understanding of why the first four attempts (c1, c2, c3, and c4) in my example fail to compile.  It boils down to me not understanding what the compile-time class returned by this.getClass() is.

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class MyClass<T extends MyClass<?>> {

   public Constructor<T> findConstructor() 
       throws NoSuchMethodException {

      Class<? extends MyClass<T>> c1 = this.getClass(); // what I expect from getClass() documentation
      Class<? extends T>          c2 = this.getClass(); // what I'd like even better
      Class<T>                    c3 = this.getClass(); // this would be fine too
      Class<MyClass>              c4 = this.getClass(); // I'd even accept this, losing the T parameter
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
         Class<T>                 c5 = (Class<T>) this.getClass();   // works, but eww

      Constructor<T> constructor = c5.getConstructor();    // my goal

      return constructor;
   }  // findConstructor()

} // MyClass<T>
```

Anyone?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some client code using this class as well?

Comment: It's a bit complex.  The idea is to write a method which returns a map of objects representing rows from an arbitrary database table.  Parameters include a database connection, the table name, and column name / field name correspondences.  The method uses reflection to get data type information for the columns, and uses the constructor found in my original question to create the instances of the returned map.  The functionality is spread over multiple methods and I already have the answer I sought, so posting the code is probably not necessary.  If you're curious I'll do so, though.

Answer (score 2):

Javadoc of [`getClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--) (emphasis is from javadoc):

> Returns the runtime class of this `Object`. The returned `Class` object is the object that is locked by `static synchronized` methods of the represented class.
>
> **The actual result type is `Class<? extends |X|>` where `|X|` is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which `getClass` is called.** For example, no cast is required in this code fragment:
>
> ```
> Number n = 0;
> Class<? extends Number> c = n.getClass();
> ```

So, since your class is `MyClass<T extends MyClass<?>>`, and the erasure of that is `MyClass`, that means that `|X|` is `MyClass`, hence the *actual result type* is:

```
Class<? extends MyClass>
```

The first 4 statements are not assignment compatible with that type, and the fifth will compile because of the class cast.

---

Since erasure means that you don't know what `T` is at runtime, there is **no way to return a constructor to type `T`**.

Remember, `T` doesn't have to be the same subclass of `MyClass` that is used to call `findConstructor()`. Example:

```
public class Foo extends MyClass<Foo> {
}
public class Bar extends MyClass<Foo> {
}
```

If you called `bar.findConstructor()`, it simply can't return a constructor to `Foo`, because it doesn't know that `T` is a `Foo` at runtime (because of type erasure).

Comment: Got it!  Thanks.  My missing cognitive link was that I was ignoring the non-inheritance of constructors.  I thought that it was a compile-time issue, and that therefore the method should have seen that 'this' was of class MyClass<T> and it should have compiled.   Your post implied that since this could be a subclass of MyClass<T>, which would generate an inappropriate Constructor.  Thanks!

Comment: @BruceFeist: Inheritance of constructors has nothing to do with it. And a constructor for a subclass of `T` (i.e. a `Constructor<? extends T>`) indeed does construct a `T` (because an instance of a subclass of `T` is an instance of `T`). In fact, since `Constructor` is a Producer (PECS), you should always use `Constructor<? extends T>` and not `Constructor<T>`. But the problem here is that you don't even have a `Constructor<? extends T>` (because you don't have a `Class<? extends T>`); you can only get a `Constructor<? extends MyClass>` (because you only have a `Class<? extends MyClass>`).

Answer (score 0):

It's clear in the Javadoc that the return type of `Object#getClass()` is `Class<?>`, with this note added:

> **The actual result type is Class <? extends |X|> where |X| is the
>   erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is
>   called.**  For example, no cast is required in this code fragment:
>
> ```
> Number n = 0; 
> Class<? extends Number> c = n.getClass();
> ```

This makes the compile time return type:

```
Class<? extends MyClass> c1 = this.getClass();
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--

Comment: I understood that, but incorrectly thought that it would be resolved at compile-time into Class<T>.  Thanks!